# How to retrieve formals of a primitive function?

Tags: r

For the moment, at least, this is an exercise in learning for me, so the actual functions or their complexity is not the issue.  Suppose I write a function whose argument list includes some input variables and a function name, passed as a string.  This function then calculates some variables internally and "decides" how to feed them to the function name I've passed in.

For nonprimitive functions, I can do (for this example, assume non of my `funcname` functions have any arguments other than at most `(x,y,z)`. If they did, I'd have to write some code to search for matching `names(formals(get(funcname)))` so as not to delete the other arguments):

```
foo <- function (a,b,funcname) {
    x <- 2*a
    y <- a+3*b
     z <- -b
    formals(get(funcname)) <- list(x=x, y=y, z=z)
    bar <- get(funcname)()
return(bar)
}
```

And the nice thing is,  even if the function `funcname` will execute without error even if it doesn't use `x`, `y` or `z` (so long as there are no other args that don't have defaults) .
The problem with "primitive" functions is I don't know any way to find or modify their formals.  Other than writing a wrapper, e.g.  `foosin <-function(x) sin(x)`, is there a way to set up my `foo` function to work with both primitive and nonprimitive function names as input arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`formals(args(FUN))` can be used to get the formals of a primitive function.

You could add an `if` statement to your existing function.

```
> formals(sum)
# NULL
> foo2 <- function(x) {
      if(is.primitive(x)) formals(args(x)) else formals(x)
      ## formals(if(is.primitive(x)) args(x) else x) is another option
  }
> foo2(sum)
# $...
#
#
# $na.rm
# [1] FALSE
#
> foo2(with)
# $data
# 
#
# $expr
#
#
# $...
```

Comment: Actually,  `formals(args(non_primitive_func))` returns the same thing as just `formals(non_primitive_func)` .  But I didnt think of that doubling-up thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Right, but without `args` it would never get the primitive's formals.  I'm sure we could adjust it as to not repeat `formals` in the code.

Comment: Update: unfortunately this is only half the battle.  I still can't redefine the formals of a Primitive the way I redefined them for my sample function. The best I can think of so far (for Primitives) is to check which of `x,y,z` exist in the current function `funcname` and build a `do.call` with that sublist.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - are you sure that you actually *can* redefine the formals of a primitive?  I'm under the impression that those functions are "locked" and cannot be redefined.

Comment: That was my point: I'll create a list like `arglist=list(x=5,y=3)` which includes only valid argument names for my input function, and then `do.call(get(funcname),arglist)` will work so long as I haven't left out any required arguments (which I deem to be my own fault).

Comment: I'll see if I can help.  But I'm sure one of the  R wizards will be along shortly with a definitive answer

Comment: @RichardScriven: Is there a reason why we can't just use `formals(args(x))` even for non-primitive functions? That would save the check...

Answer (score 1):

Building on Richard S' response, I ended up doing the following.  Posted just in case anyone else ever tries do things as weird as I do.

EDIT: I think more type-checking needs to be done. It's possible that `coleqn` could be
the name of an object, in which case `get(coleqn)` will return some data.  Probably I need
to add a `if(is.function(rab))` right after the `if(!is.null(rab))`. (Of course, given that I wrote the function for my own needs, if I was stupid enough to pass an object, I deserve what I get :-) ).

```
# "coleqn" is the input argument, which is a string that could be either a function
# name or an expression.

rab<-tryCatch(get(coleqn),error=function(x) {} )
#oops, rab can easily be neither NULL nor a closure. Damn.
if(!is.null(rab)) {
# I believe this means it must be a function
# thanks to Richard Scriven of SO for this fix to handle primitives
# we are not allowed to redefine primitive's formals.
    qq <- list(x=x,y=y,z=z) 
#  matchup the actual formals names
#  by building a list of valid arguments to pass to do.call 
    argk<-NULL
    argnames<-names(formals(args(coleqn)))
    for(j in 1:length(argnames) )
        argk[j]<-which(names(qq)==argnames[1] )
    arglist<-list()
    for(j in 1:length(qq) ) 
        if(!is.na(argk[j])) arglist[[names(qq)[j]]]<-qq[[j]]
    colvar<- do.call(coleqn,arglist) 
    } else {
# the input is just an expression (string), not a function
        colvar <- eval(parse(text=coleqn)) 
    }
```

The result is an object generated either by the expression or the function just created, using variables internal to the main function (which is not shown in this snippet)